# Which are recommended external Java Api's to use in web application

Tags: java, performance

I am working on Spring , Hibernate and Restfull webservice based java application. I want to use some external API's. (For optimization). Can anyone please recommend me some API's which are are used in Realtime projects.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking for... you need api ok, but for what purpose?

Comment: You probably want to know about popular general purpose libraries, and not about "external API". Try Apache Commons.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for connecting to multiple API listed Below with code optimization as Priority to integrate (Spring , Hibernate and Restfull webservice based java application. )
Integration with External Systems

```
ReST/HTTP
FTP/SFTP
Twitter
WebServices (SOAP and ReST)
TCP/UDP
JMS
RabbitMQ
Email
```

Then you can add the External API's using  a dependencies mechanism